# Cannot update SQL database from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I am having trouble updating fields in SQL database via stored procedure.
Following is the c# code. I get no syntax error or anything neither in the stored procedure nor in c# code.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
        SqlCommand commandp = new SqlCommand("spUpdateCmpStructure", dbcon.con);
        commandp.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        commandp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpID", txtCmp.Text.ToString());
        commandp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpName", txtCmp.Text.ToString());
        commandp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpDesc", txtDetails.Text.ToString());
        commandp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpAddress", txtAddress.Text.ToString());
        commandp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpType", cbType.Text.ToString());
        commandp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpParent", cbParent.Text.ToString());

        dbcon.openConnection();

        int check = commandp.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (check > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(txtCmp.Text.ToString() + " Updated");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(txtCmp.Text.ToString() + " Update Failed");
        }

        dbcon.closeConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
         finally 
         {
             dbcon.closeConnection();
         }
```

and following is the stored procedure

```
USE [xxx]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Spupdatecmpstructure] @cmpID      VARCHAR(10),
                                             @cmpName    VARCHAR(50),
                                             @cmpDesc    VARCHAR(100),
                                             @cmpAddress VARCHAR(50),
                                             @cmpType    VARCHAR(20),
                                             @cmpParent  VARCHAR(50)
AS
  BEGIN
      UPDATE cmpStructure
      SET    cmpName = @cmpName,
             cmpDesc = @cmpDesc,
             cmpAddress = @cmpAddress,
             cmpType = @cmpType,
             cmpParent = @cmpParent
      WHERE  cmpID = @cmpID
  END
```

Comment: What is your column types? What is your command looks like when you add parameter values? After you add parameter values, is it update in your database manager (sql server management studio)? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: "I get no syntax error or anything neither in the stored procedure nor in c# code" - ok, and what about runtime errors/exceptions? Are there any? Have you debugged it and seen what parameters values are passed to stored procedure?

Comment: make sure `@cmpID` has some value while it is passed to `SP` and the `@cmpID` value should be present in `cmpStructure` table to update atleast one row.

Comment: Run sqlProfiler and see what are the values of parameters when c# executes your sp, then by these values you can find what is wrong

Comment: @SonerGönül it is not updated there either. I also get no exception. Other procedures like search and insert work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hereby you can see, the id and the name field are bounded with same value **txtCmp.Text.ToString()**

```
commandp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpID", txtCmp.Text.ToString());
commandp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpName", txtCmp.Text.ToString());
```

Comment: Man I am so sorry. Such a little mistake.

Comment: It happens to everyone of us, everyday! :)